# How to run function after each FOR loop step

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, settimeout

I need to transfer object from array `pts` to array `test` one by one, after each I need to call function mimicSvg with array test

I try everything:

```
var test=[{"X":"300","Y":"400"}];
setTimeout(function () {
    for(var m=1;m<25;m++){
    var q = pts[m].X;
    var e = pts[m].Y;
    console.log(test);
    test.push({"X":q,"Y":e});
    mimicSvg(test,1);

    }
    }, 1000);
```

and this:

```
var test=[{"X":"300","Y":"400"}];
for(var m=1;m<pts.length;m++){

    var q = pts[m].X;
    var e = pts[m].Y;
    console.log(test);
    test.push({"X":q,"Y":e});
    alert(m);
  setInterval(mimicSvg, 2000, test, 1);

  }
```

and also this:

```
setTimeout( "mimicSvg(test,1);test.push({"X":q,"Y":e});",m*3000 );
```

and this similar:

```
setTimeout(function() {mimicSvg(test,1); test.push({"X":q,"Y":e});},m*3000 );
```

But I cant run function after each transfer...
My console looks like this:
[image]

and:[image]

I so confused... WHere I wrong? Why I cant get test like this:

```
after 1. loop array[1] -> run function with this array
after 2nd loop array[2] -> run function ...
etc....
```

Comment: It is not clear what your expected result is and what the actual result is? Could be that mimicSvg should be called and it is not. If so, how do you know?

Comment: after each step I transfer one object from PTS to TEST and then I need to run function, then go 2. step for loop where m=2 ... ...

Comment: Have you thought about using events?  If you are using jQuery (or Backbone or some other frameworks), you could think about triggering a custom event and setup custom event listeners.

Comment: What is mimicSvg doing?  Does it need the entire `test` array?

Comment: mimicSvg need test with m numbers of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**
try this:

```
var set_time;
var m = 0;
var add_array = function(){
    if(m < pts.length){
       var q = pts[m].X;
       var e = pts[m].Y;
       console.log(test);
       test.push({"X":q,"Y":e});
       mimicSvg(test,1);
       m++;
       set_time = setTimeout(add_array,1000);//it call itself again and again until m is more than the length of the array'
    }
}
set_time = setTimeout(add_array,1000);
```

I think your problem is `for` run the function all of your arrays immediately. 
I suppose you want to run the function every 1 sec so that's solution.
it's called "Rucursion" this function will called itself until m is more than the length of the array(`if(m < pts.length)`).
 
if it's not what you want,please explain me more details.
hope it helps :)

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you for suggestion :) I'll edit it and next time I'll write how it does or why it should in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're complicating things by adding the `setTimeout` or `setInterval` methods.  Can you not simply run the `mimicSvg` call in the loop?  Assuming that's right, here is my solution:

```
  /** assuming pts and mimicSvg is available in this scope */

  var testData = [{x: 300, y:400}];

  for(var m=1;m<pts.length;m++){
    var pt = pts[m];
    var itemForTest = {X: pt.X, Y: pt.Y}

    console.log("Test Data at iteration " + m, testData);

    testData.push(itemForTest);

    mimicSvg(testData, m);

  }
```

If there is a good reason for the `setTimeout` or `setInterval` calls, please explain why you need those.